# Rolar chat para baixo quando receber nova mensagem PHP MYSQL AJAX JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Estou pesquisando a mais ou menos 4 dias sobre como rolar a barra de rolagem do meu chat quando receber novas mensagens e rolar para cima para ver as mensagens anteriores.

Fiz um script usando **setInterval**, porém quando tento rolar a `div` para cima, a mesma retorna para baixo, ficando praticamente "colada" no rodapé.

O que pode ser? Aguardo respostas, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

vc cria uma variavel assim que a PÁGINA abre.
tipo var contagem = 0;
daí vc faz uma requisição só pra contar quantas mensagens tem no DB.
se a quantidade for maior que a variável contagem vc solicita as mensagens e atualiza a contagem, com: contagem = qtdMensagem;
daí ql a vantagem disso ?

1. já que tem uma requisição sendo feita a cada segundo, evita q a aplicação(whatever) fique imprimindo o tempo inteiro, oq acaba chateando o usuário que n consegue subir o scroll p ler mensagens antigas.
2. vc ainda dá p fazer o som de nova mensagem (tipo msn, whatsapp, fb, skype, etc), já pensou se o chat apita sem parar a cada segundo ? rsss